# SQL timeouts executing reader on view that converts Base64 to binary

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ado.net

We have files stored Base64-encoded in a SQL Server table. We need to stream the files for downloading as binary data, so we query a view that converts the Base64 column to `varbinary`:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[FilesView]
AS      
    SELECT
        f.Id,
        CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("f.FileContents"))', 'varbinary(max)') AS FileContents,
    FROM [Files] f
```

`FileContents` is in the files table, defined as `varchar(max)`.

We query this column using ADO.NET and use a `SqlDataReader` to stream the contents:

```
private async Task<Stream> FileStream(Guid id)
{
    string commandText = "SELECT FileContents FROM FilesView WHERE Id = @id";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, (SqlConnection)context.Database.GetDbConnection()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));

        if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync();
        }

        SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

        if (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            return reader.GetStream(0);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This was working well for us and the file download would start immediately, however after shipping we have a handful of customers who are getting exceptions on the `cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync` line:

> Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

From what they are saying these aren't huge files either, less than 1 MB. In our testing we used much larger files and had no timeout issues. We had them increase the command timeout to 60 or more seconds and it mostly corrected it, but took a long time, and the issue still comes up. Since the exception occurs when opening the reader, my assumption is that the Base64 to binary conversion is what is causing a timeout.

Why only some instances? Is there a specific feature/option in SQL Server we should be checking or changing that could be causing this? I don't know the hardware specs of their database server but I suppose it could just be a case of being too underpowered for the conversion?

Comment: I suggest you monitor the db server on the problem clients. My guess is a wait on a resource, such as a memory grant. You could reduce the storage size by over 50% by storing the raw binary bytes.

Comment: There may be differences in SQL Server versions or database tuning. It's surprising how bad many organizations do in both respects. You may find out that the exception occurs in lower versions or even Sql Express (yes). Or with poorly dimensioned host machines or non-optimized tempdb's. Just to mention a few things I encounter in the field.

Comment: We need to see a query plan to know for sure, you can share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan.  I note that the connection and reader are not being disposed with `using`, which it should be. `return reader.GetStream(0)` is just wrong, given that you would be disposing the reader and closing the connection, you would get `InvalidOperationException`. Instead, read the stream there and return the result `using (var s =reader.GetStream(0)) { await s.ReadAsync` or whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this particular client was using SQL Server 2017, but had their Compatibility level set to SQL Server 2012 (110). Moved it up to 130 and the queries now run in milliseconds.